# Visual Basic 6.0

Tags: visual-basic-6, sql-server-2008

Olá sou novo nessa linguagem. Estou criando um formulário de cadastro de alunos com o SQL server 2008 e conexão .ADO. Na hora de inserir e salvar os dados de cadastro o botão cadastrar inseri duas linhas repetidas.

Eis o código do botão cadastrar:

```
'------------Botão CADASTRAR--------------
Private Sub CmbCadastrar_Click()

     SQL = "INSERT INTO alunos(nome,idade,datanasc) VALUES ('" + TextNomeAluno + "', '" + TextIdade + "', '" + TextDataNasc + "')"


If TextNomeAluno = "" Then
    MsgBox "CAMPO NOME VAZIO!!! Por favor, insira os valores corretos", vbExclamation
    TextNomeAluno.SetFocus
 Exit Sub
End If

If TextIdade = "" Then
    MsgBox "CAMPO IDADE VAZIO!!! Por favor, insira os valores corretos", vbExclamation
    TextIdade.SetFocus
 Exit Sub
End If

If TextDataNasc = "" Then
    MsgBox "CAMPO DATA VAZIO!!! Por favor, insira os valores corretos", vbExclamation
    TextDataNasc.SetFocus
 Exit Sub
End If


     Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
     rs.Open SQL, cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockReadOnly
     MsgBox "DADOS CADASTRADOS COM SUCESSO.", vbInformation

     cn.Execute SQL

End Sub

'-------- Botão LIMPAR LISTA-------------
Private Sub CmbLimpaLista_Click()
    LstvAlunos.ListItems.Clear
End Sub

'-------- Botão LIMPAR------------------
Private Sub CmbLimpar_Click()
    TextNomeAluno.Text = Empty
    TextIdade.Text = Empty
    TextDataNasc.Text = Empty
End Sub

'---------Botão LISTAR-------------------
Private Sub CmbListar_Click()

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

    cn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;pwd=hcac10;Initial Catalog=db_Escola;Data Source=. "

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    'SQL = "SELECT  codaluno,nome,idade,CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),datanasc,103) FROM dbo.alunos"

    SQL = "SELECT * FROM alunos"

    rs.Open SQL, cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockReadOnly

Do While Not rs.EOF

    Set item = LstvAlunos.ListItems.Add(, , rs.Fields("codaluno"))

    item.SubItems(1) = rs.Fields("nome")
    item.SubItems(2) = rs.Fields("idade")
    item.SubItems(3) = rs.Fields("datanasc")

    rs.MoveNext

Loop

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Muito estranho isso, deve ter alguma coisa chamando seu método do botão duas vezes e guardando as informações em cache , mas você pode tenta fazer isso, `"if(not exists(select * from alunos where nome = '" + TextNomeAluno + "' and idade = '" + TextIdade + "' and datanasc =  '" + TextDataNasc + "'))
   INSERT INTO alunos(nome,idade,datanasc) VALUES ('" + TextNomeAluno + "', '" + TextIdade + "', '" + TextDataNasc + "')"`  e altera para ficar depois das validações dos campos.

Comment: Esta dando erro de sintaxe

Comment: idade é um campo int?  se for retire as aspas simples do '" + TextIdade + "'

Comment: Sim é um campo int.

Comment: Como ficou a alteração e qual erro deu

Comment: Expected Expression

Answer (score 0):

Está inserindo duas vezes porque existem duas instruções no seu código que executam o comando SQL:

```
rs.Open SQL, cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockReadOnly
```

e

```
cn.Execute SQL
```

Não é necessário criar um objeto `Recordset` se seu objetivo é executar uma instrução que não retorna registros. Para isso use o comando `Execute` apenas.

Comment: ok funcionou direitinho

Comment: Gostaria de criar uma função para um botão pesquisar pela matrícula ou pelo nome do aluno e assim como retorno ao clicar o botão no textbox de pesquisa ele preencheria os campos com os dados já cadastrados e assim poderia escolher o que fazer: alterar, excluir por exemplo. Preciso de uma ajuda urgente tenho 2 semanas para entregar esse projeto aqui na empresa se eu pudesse me adiantar com a ajuda de vcs ficaria grato.

Comment: Poder ser um exemplo genérico não há problema, quero apenas compreender como se faz

Comment: A sua função "CmbListar_Click" já tem quase todo o código necessário.
Basta alterar SQL = "SELECT * FROM alunos" e adicionar ao final "WHERE matricula = N" (N vem da pesquisa).
Troque o WHILE por IF (já que é pra retornar somente um registro) e dentro dele direcione os campos do rs para as textbox adequadas.